# Entering a password using System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, process

I have created a new instance of the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class.

The `StartInfo.Filename` property is the name of my command line application (`OpenSSL.exe`). I can use `StandardInput.WriteLine` to send commands to this application. This works fine until I reach the point where I am asked for a password, in which case `StandardInput.WriteLine` doesn't do anything.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked this out, I added a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` then used `SendKeys.SendWait` to send each letter of my password to the application, followed by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Whats the point in giving me a -1 if you're not going to provide any constructive criticism or an alternative answer?

Comment: The downvote seems strange: the answer looks like a neat way around the problem.